# Search and replace specific tag value in XML file with sed command

Tags: sed, replace, xml

I have a task where by I have to manipulate an XML file through a bash shell script.

Here are the steps:

- Query XML file for a value.
- Replace the value of a different element    with the new value.

Here is the sample xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.sendPoweredByHeader</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>
    <param-value>25</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>testing</param-name>
    <param-value>25</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

I need to update the parm value of  `<param-value>25</param-value>` to `<param-value>3</param-value>` using a shell script.

Any idea what will be the SED command to update only param value of param name(`<param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>`)?

i tried with below command,

```
sed -i 's/<param-value>25<\/param-value>/<param-value>3<\/param-value>/' test.xml
```

but this command will update all the param-values. i need to update only for com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession

Comment: @choroba can you please let me know how we can achieve this using bash shell script.

Comment: Choroba may not see this, since you deleted the post that they answered...

Comment: Is that the complete XML document? It doesn't have a root node?

Comment: yes its complete XML Doc, also its having root node also, i just gave sample example.

Comment: @JeffSchaller...by mistake my old post got deleted...choroba has given me some solution i need some clarification on that.

Answer (score 3):

Using XMLStarlet, and assuming that the document has a root node:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
    -u '//context-param[param-name = "com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession"]/param-value[. = 25]' \
    -v 3 file.xml
```

This selects the correct `param-value` node (the one that has a value of 25 (drop the `[. = 25]` bit if the old value is unimportant) and is a child node of the `context-param` node whose `param-name` child node has the value `com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession`), and changes its value to 3.

The resulting document will be (with a fake `root` node inserted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.sendPoweredByHeader</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>
    <param-value>3</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>testing</param-name>
    <param-value>25</param-value>
  </context-param>
</root>
```

Comment: thank you so much for the solution, sorry but i am new to shell/bash script...i tried your command, i am getting below error: xmlstarlet: command not found

Comment: @user3611640 Well, yes. It relies on having the `xmlstarlet` tool installed.  On some Unices, it may be installed as just `xml`, on others you will have to install it from the packaging system.  It's available on Linux and BSD, at least.

Comment: @kusalananda....i am not sure i will be able to install xmlstarlet at client box, any other approach is there to achieve this..like using xml or sed command.

Comment: @user3611640 I'm not going to give you a `sed` answer. Structured document formats like XML (or JSON or even some forms of CSV) require parsing by a real parser, not a line-oriented text tool like `sed` or `awk` or any of the other standard Unix text manipulation tools.  You could also parse the XML in Python or Perl with some XML module, obviously.

Comment: @kusalananda...i got the solution using sed command, also its working as expected.                                                                                                            sed -i '/<param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession<\/param-name>/{n;s/<param-value>3<\/param-value>/<param-value>25<\/param-value>/}' web.xml

Answer (score -1):

```
sed -i 's#<param-value>25</param-value>#<param-value>3</param-value>#' test.xml
```

Comment: This would possibly change irrelevant lines in the document. In the example given, two lines would be changed instead of the intended single line. In fact, this is exactly equivalent to the command that the user in the question tried for themselves.

Answer (score -2):

using below sed command, we can update the specific tag value:-

```
sed -i '/<param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession<\/param-name>/{n;s/<param-value>3<\/param-value>/<param-value>25<\/param-value>/}' test.xml
```